# GTK Window Cover Entire Screen

Tags: window, gtk, gdk

I'm working on a small educational piece of work, I create a window and its supposed to cover the entire monitor. However "special" areas are not being covered as seen in the screnshot at bottom. My window is a solid red with no menu bar scroll bar etc, is there anyway to make this cover the top menu bar and the dock. In my screenshot I am testing on Ubuntu and Mint, this is consistent behavior on Gtk OS's I need to be ablve ot set my window so it covers all things is this possible?

I tried `gdk_window_fullscreen` but it's not doing anything, not even fullscreen, do you think its because I'm running this function from another thread? How would I know if this function needs to be run from the main thread?

### Incomplete coverage on Ubuntu:

[image]

### Incomplete coverage on Mint:

[image]

### Code Tried

1. A frameless window is opened using Firefox code from main thread:

   ```
   var aEditorDOMWindow = Services.ww.openWindow(null, core.addon.path.content + 'panel.xul', '_blank', 'chrome,width=1,height=1,screenX=0,screenY=0', null);
   ```
2. Now after load of it completes then the GdkWindow* of this window is obtained on the main thread and passed to another thread as a string
3. The thread now takes the string to GdkWindow* then that to GtkWindow*

   ```
           var gdkWinPtr = ostypes.TYPE.GdkWindow.ptr(ctypes.UInt64(aHwndStr));
           var gtkWinPtr = ostypes.HELPER.gdkWinPtrToGtkWinPtr(gdkWinPtr);
   ```
4. The thread then executes `gtk_window_set_keep_above` because if there was another app was focused it will focus this guy, and it will keep him on top of existing full screen windows

   ```
    var rez_topIt = ostypes.API('gtk_window_set_keep_above')(gtkWinPtr, true);
   ```
5. The thread used to then run `gtk_window_present` but I removed it as I noticed it would crash the app, this was the code:

   ```
      var rez_focus = ostypes.API('gtk_window_present')(gtkWinPtr);
   ```
6. EXPERIMENTAL STUFF I tried but it didnt work to make the window cover the special UI:

   - `ostypes.API('gdk_window_set_type_hint')(gdkWinPtr, ostypes.CONST.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN);`
   - `ostypes.API('gtk_window_set_position')(gtkWinPtr, ostypes.CONST.GTK_WIN_POS_NONE);`
   - ```
     var geom = ostypes.TYPE.GdkGeometry();
     geom.max_width = aOptions.fullWidth;
     geom.max_height = aOptions.fullHeight;
     var rez_geo = ostypes.API('gtk_window_set_geometry_hints')(gtkWinPtr, null, geom.address(), ostypes.CONST.GDK_HINT_MAX_SIZE);
     ```
7. Now the thread work is done and it goes to main thread. Now the main thread uses firefox javascript to move the window to top left most origin (which i calculated earlier with Gdk calls) and also sets the width and height of this window to that calculated of all the monitors (i did this earlier with other gdk calls)

   ```
           aEditorDOMWindow.moveTo(collCanMonInfos[0].xTopLeft, collCanMonInfos[0].yTopLeft);
           aEditorDOMWindow.resizeTo(collCanMonInfos[0].nWidth, collCanMonInfos[0].nHeight);
   ```

This results in the window SOMETIMES covering all monitors, other times just the one it opened on. And it never covers special UI like the taskbar/dock/menubars.

If you can please advise on how to acheive a window that fully covers everything that would be very appreciated, I'm trying to teach some people some stuff and I ran into a mess.

Here is a youtube video of the addon I am making: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJM5NQK67N4

I discontinued using `gdk_fullscreen` because when it worked intermittently it would not allow the window to expand outside the one monitor.

Comment: Can you post some code, please? For multi-threading in GTK+, see this: http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness

Comment: Thanks antoyo, you can see Noi's and my work here. If you have firefox you can install this addon from github repo with [github extensions installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/),  the code is here, we start from the main thread we open a new window and get `GdkWindow*`: https://github.com/yajd/NativeShot/blob/487f20746316a22e7912c3add5db0931c015d628/bootstrap.js#L186-L198 this then calls another thread to do some stuff in main: https://github.com/yajd/NativeShot/blob/487f20746316a22e7912c3add5db0931c015d628/modules/workers/MainWorker.js#L115-L144

Comment: and after that is finished calling it complets with back in the main thread https://github.com/yajd/NativeShot/blob/487f20746316a22e7912c3add5db0931c015d628/bootstrap.js#L205-L233 @antoyo

Comment: Thanks both of you Ill update thread with code.

Comment: @antoyo i added the code used, and also a youtube screencast

Comment: I honestly don't think you can underestimate the fact that you

Comment: I literally have no idea what happens when you ask Firefox to create windows for you, and how does that interact with the system. You're piling up assumptions over assumptions.

Comment: Thanks @ebassi for your reply ive been struggling with this.

Answer (score 2):

Panels are usually implemented with struts, and window managers can decide never to allow windows to cover them; that's one of the reasons why the whole idea of "full screen window" was introduced: it gives the window manager a hint that the window that requested to be full screen should cover all other windows; have no decorations; and also cover all eventual "system" components, like panels.

Comment: Aw man so maybe my ideal solution is to just make a new window per monitor and set each  window to fullscreen so it covers the monitor its on?