# GDK2 Alternative for gdk_window_set_fullscreen_mode

Tags: gtk, gdk

I'm trying to set my window to be `GDK_FULLSCREEN_ON_ALL_MONITORS` but for this I have to use `gdk_window_set_fullscreen_mode`, what is the GDK2 version of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no GDK 2.x version of this API. The `set_fullscreen_mode()` method was added in 2013, long after GTK+ 2.x was API frozen; this means that no new function is going to be added to the GTK+ 2.x API.

The implementation of the `set_fullscreen_mode()` on X11 is not trivial; it implies getting the XINERAMA index of each monitor and sending a specially crafter `ClientMessage` to the running window manager for the `_NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS` atom. You can see the implementation used in GDK attached to [the issue that introduced it](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=691856).

If you need this kind of functionality, you will have to use GTK+ 3.x.

Comment: Thanks much @ebassi, I do need this functionality on gtk2 systems as well, would it be enough to position a window at top left most origin, and then give that window the height and width of all the monitors combined? I just need to ensure that the window shows over any special widgets like unity dock etc. I'm making a screenshot thing like this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightshot/ On click it covers all with the full screenshot then user can edit that image.

Comment: You can use the geometry of the monitors, and if you use a window that is not managed by the window manager (i.e. a `GTK_WINDOW_POPUP` top level GtkWindow) then you may be able to put it over the whole screen area.

Comment: May you please see my topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366706/gtk-window-cover-entire-screen i cant seem to get it :(