# gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid alternative for GTK3

Tags: gtk, x11, gtk3, gtk2

Recently an app I use (Firefox) was upgraded to GTK3. My plugin relied on `gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid` as Firefox stores the `GDKWindow*` in some vars available to us developers. I make plugins.

Is there a GTK3 way to go from `GDKWindow*` to `XID`?

Thanks

Comment: [`gdk_x11_window_get_xid()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-X-Window-System-Interaction.html#gdk-x11-window-get-xid) (or maybe [`GDK_WINDOW_XID()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-X-Window-System-Interaction.html#GDK-WINDOW-XID:CAPS), but IDK what the difference is). But why do you need the X11 window? GTK+ 3 runs on much more than X11; if the window is a Wayland window, this will fail. (You can determine the type with `GDK_IS_X11_WINDOW()`.)

Comment: Thanks very much @andlabs that was the solution! I needit because in Firefox they expose the string of the GdkWindow* to javascript. I do all my native stuff in background thread. So I send the thread this string of the pointer, then on that side I turn it into an actual pointer (not string) and then i can work with it. But GDK and X11 are not thread safe, so i have to get a XID out of it (which is XWindow) and use xcb.

Comment: Does something prevent you from calling `gdk_threads_add_idle()`? I'm not familiar with how the Firefox extension system works.

Comment: Thanks very much @andlabs that is a great question. I struggled with that and in the end found out that my app (Firefox) is not capable of creating callbacks on the thread to be called from mainthread. As when its time to call, it looks for the callback on the mainthread and doesnt find it and crashes. This is a limitation of the firefox js-ctypes API. In Firefox, if I am coding in C, I can use `gdk_threads_add_idle` just fine, but from js-ctypes it doesnt work. I filed a bug and I hope they fix it :)

Comment: All right then. Does the `gdk_x11_window_get_xid()` function work in the meantime?

Comment: @andlabs Yep it does thanks very much! if you can move to solution i would love to accept :)

Comment: This is offtopic but @andlabs by any chance would you know how to fix this - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/issues/27 - I created topics about this issue in the past but i havent been able to resolve it. Here are my old topics with this improper overlap issue - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31366706/1828637

Comment: I wouldn't; sorry. Maybe the whole window needs to be queued for redraw initially? Maybe it's an issue with the graphics driver that user has? Good luck.

Comment: Forgot to +1 you on that andlabs, just did :)